# VIM - How to I make Undo put me back in what ever mode I was on previously?

Tags: vim, macvim, undo

I often go around editing things in normal mode only to realise my change was not intended, as such, I undo and then press K/L/J/H to continue but meanwhile I am already in insert mode, so I have to get out of it first.

I would like to insert a rule on my .vimrc to put me back on the mode I was on just before any changes that I did.

IE: shift+s (delete line and start editing) -> undo : Back in normal mode
Bonus: ciw -> asdahsdasdh -> undo: Back in normal mode

PS: I am actually using Undo with Command+Z, the default MacOSX undo combination.

Comment: Aren't you already in normal mode when you undo? I assume you undo by pressing `u`?

Comment: That would be correct if I was using U, I did not realise that would confuse anyone, I am just so used to using command+z (default macosx undo) that I havent actually moved on to use U, I will ammend my question.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos I'm afraid the true and easiest solution to this is to stop using command+z. I am a Mac user as well. But using escape+u is more natural and is the way Vim is intended to be used. One super important point though: I have my caps lock key remaped to esc. I can't live without it. This was the original position in keyboards when these editors were originally used. [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) can do this for you. I also use Karabiner (same website) to control+space as the caps lock remap (didn't want to lose it, but is rarely used). Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: My caps lock is already ESC, I remapped it using Seil too :) as for caps lock, I dont really use it regardless, I always did shift+key to get the uppercase version. I agree that using U would be the easiest solution. However I wanted to know if it was possible since its one of those habits that is hard to let go. Obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X is capturing the <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> keyboard event and handling undo at the application level, so any mapping for `<D-z>` will be ignored. However, you can override this to do what you want.

First, add a mapping to your .vimrc:

```
if has("gui_running")
    inoremap <D-z> <Esc>:undo<CR>
endif
```

Restart MacVim to ensure the .vimrc has been reloaded.

To get this to work you also need to tell MacVim to not use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> for the "Undo" menu item.

(These directions are based on Yosemite/El Capitan but are similar for older versions.)

1. Go to the System Preferences app.
2. Click the Keyboard icon.
3. Click the Shortcuts section.
4. Click on App Shortcuts in the left column.
5. Click the "+" button to add a new rule.
6. Choose MacVim from the Application pulldown.
7. Type "Undo" (exactly that and nothing else) in the Menu Title box.
8. Click into the Keyboard Shortcut box, and choose some shortcut you'll never actually use.
9. Click "Add", then close System Preferences.

(I chose <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>.)

Now going back to MacVim, if you pull down the Edit menu, "Undo" should have the key combination you chose, and your <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> shortcut should work as you described.

Comment: Perfect. This works underfully. Since I am using Phpstorm sometimes I will repeat the process for it too. Thank you :)